# Is default encoding for numpy array cPickle dumpe is latin-1?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, dump, iso-8859-1

Is default encoding for numpy array cPickle dumpe is latin-1 ? If so, where can I get it confirmed. For rest all it seems utf-8 encoding. This fails with numpy.array

```
In [45]: b = cPickle.dumps(('.'.join(('test',)), (numpy.array([1007261]), True, True), {}), protocol=0)                                                          

In [46]: b                                                                                                                                                       
Out[46]: b'(Vtest\np0\n(cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np1\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np2\n(I0\ntp3\nc_codecs\nencode\np4\n(Vb\np5\nVlatin1\np6\ntp7\nRp8\ntp9\nRp10\n(I1\n(I1\ntp11\ncnumpy\ndtype\np12\n(Vi8\np13\nI0\nI1\ntp14\nRp15\n(I3\nV<\np16\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp17\nbI00\ng4\n(V\x9d^\x0f\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\np18\ng6\ntp19\nRp20\ntp21\nbI01\nI01\ntp22\n(dp23\ntp24\n.'

In [47]: b = '(Vtest\np0\n(cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np1\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np2\n(I0\ntp3\nc_codecs\nencode\np4\n(Vb\np5\nVlatin1\np6\ntp7\nRp8\ntp9\nR
    ...: p10\n(I1\n(I1\ntp11\ncnumpy\ndtype\np12\n(Vi8\np13\nI0\nI1\ntp14\nRp15\n(I3\nV<\np16\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp17\nbI00\ng4\n(V\x9d^\x0f\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\
    ...: \u0000\\u0000\np18\ng6\ntp19\nRp20\ntp21\nbI01\nI01\ntp22\n(dp23\ntp24\n.'              
In [48]: cPickle.loads(b.encode('utf-8'), encoding='utf-8')                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-58c17196f700> in <module>
----> 1 cPickle.loads(b.encode('utf-8'), encoding='utf-8')
ValueError: buffer size does not match array size
In [50]: cPickle.loads(b.encode('latin1'), encoding='latin1')                                                                                                    
Out[50]: ('test', (array([1007261]), True, True), {})
```

I am dumping the data from one application and reading it from another. So, I have to convert the string to bytes before I load them using cPickle. I though cPickle.dump was always using utf-8 encoding in py3 and this made me wonder. Can someone throw my some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pickle, it's you using Latin-1 in the first place.

When you go from the output of `pickle.dumps`, ie. `b` in Out[46], to the value you assign to `b` in the next statement, then you changed the type from `bytes` to `str`. 
The way you did this change is equivalent to `b = b.decode('latin1')`.

For example, the original `b` contained the sequence `b'(V\x9d^\x0f'` (in the last third).
Let's use it to see what happened:

```
>>> b = b'(V\x9d^\x0f'
>>> b.decode('latin1')
'(V\x9d^\x0f'
```

This is what you assigned to `b` in Statement 47 (towards the end of the second line).
*Visually*, you dropped the `b` prefix of the string literal.
*Effectively*, you decoded a `bytes` object to a `str` using Latin-1.
This is because Latin-1 has a 1:1 mapping of byte values to Unicode code points.

It's now a `str`.
But pickle needs a `bytes` object, so you need to encode again.
However, if you use UTF-8 to encode, you will get a `bytes` object that is different to the original one:

```
>>> b.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
b'(V\xc2\x9d^\x0f'
```

Instead of `\x9d` you now have `\xc2\x9d`.

If you encode with Latin-1, you get the same as before:

```
>>> b.decode('latin1').encode('latin1')
b'(V\x9d^\x0f'
```

**But:** I don't quite see why this round-trip conversion would be necessary at all.
There's really no need to decode the output of `pickle.dumps` to a `str`.
You could just keep the value in a byte string all along.
Use the right type: `bytes` are for binary data (like a pickle dump), `str` is for text (unlike a pickle dump).

Comment: Actually these bytes, Out[46] are transmitted over a tunnel and the receiver will assume it as string. So I need to encode (to convert it to bytes) and then unpickle it

Comment: But why would the receiver assume it is a string if it's binary data? Aren't you the receiver of the data and can control what is happening?

Comment: Note: assuming it is a string means converting it to `str` here, as far as I understand your case. This is the same as decoding. If you can't prevent the decoding step, you need to know which codec was used for decoding (Latin-1, UTF-8...), so you can losslessly convert back.